# pytorch dataloader stucked if using opencv resize method

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, multiprocessing, pytorch, scikit-image

I can run all the cells of the tutorial notebook of Pytorch about dataloading ([pytorch tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html)).
But when I use `OpenCV` in place of `Skimage` to resize the image, the dataloader gets stuck, i.e nothing happens.

In the `Rescale` class:

```
class Rescale(object):
    .....
    def __call__(self, sample):
       ....
       #img = transform.resize(image, (new_h, new_w))
       img = cv2.resize(image, (new_h, new_w))
       .....
```

The `dataloader` and the `for loop` are defined with:

```
dataloader = DataLoader(transformed_dataset, batch_size=4,
                        shuffle=True, num_workers=4)

for i_batch, sample_batched in enumerate(dataloader):
    print(i_batch, sample_batched['image'].size(),
          sample_batched['landmarks'].size())
```

I can get the `iterator` to print something if `num_workers=0`. It looks like `opencv` does not play well with the Multiprocessing of pytorch.
I would really prefer to use same package to transform the images at train time and test time (and I am already using OpenCV for the image rescale at test time).
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `cv2.ocl.setUseOpenCL(False)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a very similar problem and that's how I solved it:

when you import cv2 set `cv2.setNumThreads(0)`
and then you can set `num_workers>0` in the dataloader in PyTorch.

Seems like OpenCV tries to multithread and somewhere something goes into a deadlock.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Except for `cv2.setNumThreads(0)`,

```
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
```

can also solve this problem.

From [Pytorch issues](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1355) these five may help (not recommended):

```
1. time.sleep(0.003)
2. pin_memory = True/False
3. num_workers = 0/1
4. from torch.utils.data.dataloader import DataLoader
5. writing 8192 to /proc/sys/kernel/shmmni
```

OpenCV and Pytorch multiprocessing don't play well together, sometimes. When running a code with OpenCV functions calls embedded in a homebrewed function parallelized in a "multiprocessing" pool, the code eventually ends up with idle processors after several calls to the pool than can fluctuate from run to run.

Forking could be the problem, forking only clones the current thread. In this case, the thread pool may wrongly assume that it has more threads than it has.

The code is waiting infinitely for a condition never signaled because the number of threads is not as expected after forking.

Spawning resets the memory after forking, forcing a re-initialization of all data structures (as the thread pool) within OpenCV.

More discussion in Github of [OpenCV issues](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/5150) and [Pytorch issues](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1355).